# Why can't I use sum of probabilities as my loss function for machine learning?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning

I'd like to understand what is the major reason that we are using loss function of the following form in machine learning (I know it is obtained by taking a logarithm of the likelihood of the probability of the data, but that doesn't really say why the other choices are bad):

$$L^{(1)}(\theta)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_i \mathrm{log}\ p(y_i|x_i; \theta)$$

Why can't we, for example, simply use the following?
$$L^{(2)}(\theta)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_i p(y_i|x_i; \theta)$$

One of the reasons I am asking is that if I try to optimize $L^{(2)}$, or simply anything else than a loss function that takes a logarithm of the probablity, the algorithm fails to learn anything (e.g. for binary classification the accuracy stays around $0.5$). I sense that it might to do with the different trade-offs between examples that both of these functions suggest, but I can't quite wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 1):

Because the sum of logarithms is the logarithm of a product, and you assume the observations are independent, so the probability of seeing the particular set of observations is the **product** (not the sum) of the individual probabilities.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But my question was more: Why is it bad to optimize for maximum "sum of probabilities" and why is it good to optimize for maximum "product of probabilities"? What goes wrong in the first case?

Comment: @ticcky The first case has no justification in real life, the second does.

Comment: neither do some areas of math, yet they are there :) ... I'm looking for a rigorous justification why optimizing a sum of probabilities is a bad thing? intuitively it does not sound bad to do - in maximum margin classification you also don't operate on probabilities and just look for something that gives you maximum gap between the classes.